# Scraping a webpage with R but 'next page' button only has event 'go to top'

Tags: jquery, html, r, web-scraping, click

I am trying to scrape the tiles of news articles from a local newspaper using rvest and RSelenium. In order to access more than the first page I need to press the 'next page' button. When I click on it through my browser it works fine, but when I do it through RSelenium nothing happens.

I believe this problem comes from the fact that the only jQuery event attached to the 'next page' button is

```js
function() {
  moveScrollToTop()
}
```

My question here is, how does the button lead to changing the content of the page in the browser? 
I need to know this in order to try to activate that mechanism through R.

[This](https://www.elcolombiano.com/negocios/economia) is the webpage I'm trying to scrape, and the button I'm referring to has `class="next-button"`.

I am sorry if this is a stupid question, I have almost no knowledge of HTML and Javascript.

The code I have to moment is:

```r
# Load libraries and specify url

library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)

url <- 'https://www.elcolombiano.com/negocios/economia'

# Connect to server

remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4445L)
remDr$open()

remDr$navigate(url)

# Find and click button

next_btn <- remDr$findElement(using = "css selector", ".next-button") 
next_btn$isElementEnabled() #Returns TRUE
next_btn$clickElement() # Returns no errors

Sys.sleep(5)

# Get source

html_data <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]

# Scrape titles

titles <- html_data %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes("#estraordinario .priority-content") %>% 
  html_text()
```

Comment: Can you provide some more of your code so we can see the issue in action? I don't want to redo all the work you've already done.

Comment: @ErrorJordan I just did. I hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the base URL is "https://www.elcolombiano.com/negocios/economia#.p:2;".  You can create a list of the desired urls and then use a loop to scrape each page.  Since this page uses javascript to load the pages, I was able to use phantomJS to load the proper pages.
Go to https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/scraping-javascript-generated-data-with-r on how to use Phantom JS

Here is a basic example:

```
baseurl<-"https://www.elcolombiano.com/negocios/economia#.p:"

setwd("/Users/user/Documents/R_Files/phantom")

library(rvest)

page<-read_html('newpage.html')
urllist<-paste0(baseurl, 1:3)

for (url in urllist) {
  print(url)
  call<-paste("./phantomjs genericpage.js", url)
  system(call)
  page<-read_html('newpage.html')
  titles <- page %>%html_nodes("#estraordinario .priority-content") %>% 
    html_text()
  print(titles)
  Sys.sleep(1)
}
```

Here is the javascript code I used:

```
// scrape web page
var page = require('webpage').create(),
  system = require('system'),
  t, address;

//Set up delay function
function sleep(delay) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    while (new Date().getTime() < start + delay);
}

if (system.args.length === 1) {
  console.log('Usage: loadspeed.js <some URL>');
  phantom.exit();
}
t = Date.now();
//Read file name and print to console
address = system.args[1];
console.log(address);

var fs = require('fs');
var path = 'newpage.html';


page.open(address, function (status) {
  console.log("Status: " + status);
   sleep(500);
    var content = page.content;
    fs.write(path, content, 'w');

    t = Date.now() - t;
  console.log('Loading time ' + t + ' msec');
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: I tried doing that but it failed. Even when I looped around the first ten pages it only returned the tiles of the first page (ten times). That is the reason why I am trying to use RSelenium to get the job done.